# Golang Error : Cannot use (type [5]int) as type int in argument to median

Tags: go

I have written a function to find the median of an odd length array--

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func median(arr ...int)(int){
    sort.Ints(arr)
    return arr[len(arr)/2]
}

func main() {

    arr := []int{1,2,3}
    med := median(arr)
    fmt.Println(med)


}
```

But on compilation, I get an error saying - `Cannot use arr (type [5]int) as type int in argument to median`

What exactly is the error? How do I fix this?

PS - I do not want to modify the median function. But what is wrong with my type of `arr` that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saying `median` is a variadic function but you're passing `arr` as the first argument instead of all the arguments.  You simply need to inform go to use `arr` as *all* the variadic arguments:

```
med := median(arr...)
```

Worked for me.